# Корректно ли выражение "словно на автомате"?

Tags: выбор-слов

*Можно ли применять выражение "словно на автомате"?*

*Он делал все, словно на автомате.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Он делал всё **словно на автомате*** (= машинально, бессознательно, непроизвольно)

Тесная связь оборота со сказуемым, нет запятой.

Сравнить: *Он делал всё машинально, **словно на автомате**.*

Выражение ***на автомате*** часто применяется в речи, кавычки не нужны.

**Пример**

С тех пор жизнь профессора словно переломилась. То есть он продолжал как-то существовать и даже работать, **но делал все словно на автомате** (Анна и Сергей Литвиновы. Мертвые не лгут).